# get a proper Json when using my class in a hashmap

Tags: java, json, spring, hashmap

I want to use my own class as a key in a hashmap.

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getI18nFile(java.util.)
{
    Map< I18nKeyEntity, String> i18nValues = new HashMap();
    return i18nValues;
}
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
{
    "I18nKeyEntity{i18nKey='qsdhfhks.description', locale='ru'}": "some description",
    "I18nKeyEntity{i18nKey='qsdhfhks.name', locale='ru'}": "some name"
}
```

this is not a proper Json. how can i get proper Json?

Comment: It is proper JSON, but it might not be the format you want.  What format do you want?

Comment: Its a proper "json object"